# Expected error can only be a 440/Automation Error?

Tags: vba, unit-testing, error-handling

### Context

I have written a little [unit testing library](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/63506/23788) in VBA, so I can write unit tests like this:

```
'@ExpectedError()
Public Sub TestCannotRegisterLoggerTwice()
    
    Dim logger As ILogger
    Set logger = MockLogger.Create("TestLogger", TraceLevel)
    
    LogManager.Register logger
    LogManager.Register logger
    
End Sub
```

The above test passes:

```
2014-10-04 16:42:55 TestCannotRegisterLoggerTwice: [PASS]
```

And if I remove the `ExpectedError` "attribute", it fails:

```
2014-10-04 16:43:49 TestCannotRegisterLoggerTwice: [INCONCLUSIVE] - Test raised an error: Automation error
```

So far, so good. Well, almost.

---

### In-Test Errors work fine!

Now if I make the test throw a *division by zero*, like this:

```
'@ExpectedError()
Public Sub TestCannotRegisterLoggerTwice()
    
    Dim logger As ILogger
    Set logger = MockLogger.Create("TestLogger", TraceLevel)
    
    Dim boom As Integer
    boom = 1 / 0
    
    LogManager.Register logger
    LogManager.Register logger
    
End Sub
```

The test is still inconclusive, but this time the error is correctly picked up:

```
2014-10-04 16:45:12 TestCannotRegisterLoggerTwice: [INCONCLUSIVE] - Test raised an error: Division by zero
```

The part I don't understand, is that in both cases, the error is raised *in the same VBAProject* - the former in a class called `LogManager` (the SUT), the latter in a class called `LogManagerTests`.

Here is the part that throws the *expected error* I'm testing for:

```
Public Sub Register(ByVal logger As ILogger)
    If Not this.Loggers.Exists(logger.Name) Then
        this.Loggers.Add logger.Name, logger
    Else
        Err.Raise LogManagerError.DuplicateLoggerError, "LogManager.Register", "There is already a logger registered with name '" & logger.Name & "'."
    End If
End Sub
```

---

### What I want

I would like to be able to decorate my test methods with an `'@ExpectedError(-2147220406)` (the `Long` representation of `LogManagerError.DuplicateLoggerError`), and be able to clean this part up, in the `TestEngine.ReflectTestMethods` method:

```
For Each prospect In classMethods

    If CanAddTestMethod(prospect, result) Then
        
        Set tMethod = New TestMethod
        Set tMethod.OwnerInstance = classInstance
        tMethod.MethodName = prospect.name
        
        If prospect.HasAttribute(ExpectedErrorAttribute) Then
            If prospect.AttributeParameters(ExpectedErrorAttribute).Count <> 0 Then
                Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1055, "TestEngine.ReflectTestMethods", "ExpectedErrorAttribute for test method '" & prospect.name & "' should not have parameters."
            End If
            
            'force an "Automation Error" to be expected, 
            'because VBA "eats" the expected error thrown in the SUT:
            tMethod.ExpectedError = 440 ' prospect.AttributeParameters(ExpectedErrorAttribute).First
            
        End If
        
        result.Add tMethod.MethodName, tMethod
    
    End If

Next
```

Is that so? I can only ever expect the SUT to throw an *Automation Error*?

---

### Something I've tried

Since the error is correctly reported when it's thrown in the actual test method, I tried this:

```
'@ExpectedError()
Public Sub TestCannotRegisterLoggerTwice()
    
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    
    Dim logger As ILogger
    Set logger = MockLogger.Create("TestLogger", TraceLevel)
    
    LogManager.Register logger
    LogManager.Register logger
    
    Exit Sub
    
CleanFail:
    
    Dim errNumber As Long
    errNumber = Err.Number
    
    Dim errSource As String
    errSource = Err.Source
    
    Dim errDescription As String
    errDescription = Err.Description

    Err.Raise errNumber, errSource, errDescription
End Sub
```

But even though `errDescription` contains the correct/expected error message, the testing library still receives an *Automation Error* with number 440.

---

#### *Why does my testing library correctly pick up a division by zero, but not a custom error?*

EDIT: Upon further experimentation, I noticed that I can successfully "expect" any built-in error, so this works:

```
'@ExpectedError(5)
Public Sub TestCannotRegisterLoggerTwice()
    
    Dim logger As ILogger
    Set logger = MockLogger.Create("TestLogger", TraceLevel)
    
    LogManager.Register logger
    LogManager.Register logger
    
End Sub
```

...provided that change my `TestEngine` code to accept parameters for an `@ExpectedError` attribute, and that I raise an error #5 / "Invalid procedure call or argument" in the SUT, instead of a custom error; I can't provide a custom error message either. This isn't ideal, because it forces the SUT to only throw built-in errors, and my testing library can't assume it's the case.

**What's so special about custom error codes in VBA?**

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's special about custom error codes in VBA.

But if the error numbers thrown in the SUT are **not** in the form of the recommended `vbObjectError + n` (as can be inferred from the `-2147220406` representation of the error code you're expecting), then any *application-defined or object-defined error* can be used, and "expected":

```
Public Enum LogManagerError
    DuplicateLoggerError = 100
    LoggerNotRegisteredError
End Enum
```

The `TestEngine` will still not "see" the custom error message, but now you can do this:

```
'@ExpectedError(100)
Public Sub TestCannotRegisterLoggerTwice()

    Dim logger As ILogger
    Set logger = MockLogger.Create("TestLogger", TraceLevel)

    LogManager.Register logger
    LogManager.Register logger

End Sub
```

And get this result:

```
2014-10-04 18:09:56 TestCannotRegisterLoggerTwice: [PASS]
```

If the `ExpectedError` attribute is removed, you get an *application-defined or object-defined error*:

```
2014-10-04 18:10:20 TestCannotRegisterLoggerTwice: [INCONCLUSIVE] - Test raised an error: Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Which is technically correct - granted, it would be nice to be able to report the custom error message in the test result, but it's just one of those limitations that have to be dealt with.

At least you can now throw different errors in the SUT, *and be able to tell whether **that** error was raised* - which is the goal to be achieved here.

Meanwhile the custom error message is still visible and displayable in "normal" code:

```
'@ExpectedError(100)
Public Sub TestCannotRegisterLoggerTwice()

    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Dim logger As ILogger
    Set logger = MockLogger.Create("TestLogger", TraceLevel)

    LogManager.Register logger
    LogManager.Register logger

    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Err.Raise Err.Number

End Sub
```

[image: "There is already a logger registered with the name 'TestLogger'."]

```
2014-10-04 18:21:24 TestCannotRegisterLoggerTwice: [PASS]
```